# How to add a ion-badge inside an ion-button in Ionic 5?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I need to get something like this

[image]

but I get this

[image]

the badge can't get over it the button, the corner is hidden. the code:

html

```
    <ion-button (click)="onClick()" color="primary" fill="solid"> 1
      <ion-badge color="dark" >2</ion-badge>
    </ion-button>
```

scss

```
ion-badge{
    position: absolute; 
    font-size: 8pt;
    right: -16px;
    top: -3px; 
}

ion-button{
    margin: 5px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible!important;
}
```

Comment: Ion-badge is an inline-block element. I don't think it can do beyond the button as long as it is in the button. You can wrap them both in a div and have the badge positioned accordingly.

Comment: @NischayaSharma could you give me an example plis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case setting `overflow: visible!important;` to `ion-button` element will not solve the issue. This is because, deep inside the `ion-button` there is a `button` with class `button-native` which is inside the shadow-dom. This class has `overflow: hidden` defined inside the style definition. You have to update this style to enable the overflow of button.

Refering to [this](https://css-tricks.com/styling-in-the-shadow-dom-with-css-shadow-parts/) tutorial you can add style for the shadow dom element as follows.

**Template**

```
<ion-button (click)="onClick()" class="custom-class" color="primary" fill="solid">
  1
  <ion-badge color="dark" >2</ion-badge>
</ion-button>
```

**CSS**

```
ion-badge {
    position: absolute; 
    font-size: 8pt;
    right: -16px;
    top: -3px; 
}

ion-button {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    // overflow: visible!important;
}

/* Setting Overflow Visible */
ion-button.custom-class::part(native) {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
  <div class="button-div">
    <ion-badge color="dark">2</ion-badge>
    <ion-button>1</ion-button>
  </div>
```

Css

```
.button-div {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  ion-badge {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

WARNING: The badge is positioned relative to the div and not the button. So if the badge shifts anywhere, adjust the width and height of the div.